# Jackson JSON - Unmarshal on create but ignore on update

Tags: spring-mvc, jackson, spring-4

Using Spring 4, I have a use case where a resource (A in the example below) has a property that should be ignored when a REST update is used (http put and patch). The property can only have a value when being created (http post). So the situation is that the unmarshalling on **create** should consider that property but it **should be ignored on update**.

```
public class A {
  private String strOnCreateAndUpdate; //persist on both create and update
  private String strOnCreateOnly; //only persist on create, never on update
  //getters & setters
}
```

In the controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/a"
public class ControllerA {
    @RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public void create(@Validated @RequestBody A req) {
        //create the record
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/{id}", method=RequestMethod.PUT)
    public void update(@PathVariable Long id, @Validated @RequestBody A req) {
        //Update the record by ignoring strOnCreateOnly
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/{id}", method=RequestMethod.PATCH)
    public void update(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Map<String,Object> reqMap){
        //Update the record by ignoring strOnCreateOnly
    }
}
```

One way I can think of (and a very in-elegant way at that), is to allow the unmarshall to happen but inside the update methods, manually set the strOnCreateOnly to its original value.

But is there a configurable way of doing it using Spring 4 and Jackson (for example, using an annotation and ignoring the property from being unmarshalled)? Even sending back an error to the callers of the API to say updating strOnCreateOnly is not allowed is fine.

Comment: let us know if you found a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `@JsonView` for that.

[**Jackson Doc Link**](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews)

Whereas you create a `View` class that will represent the action types: (Update, Create, All). Something like this

```
// View definitions:
class Views {
    static class Common { }
    static class Update extends Common { }
    static class Create extends Common { }
}
```

Apply it to your class like this

```
public class A {
    @JsonView(View.Common.class)
    private String strOnCreateAndUpdate; //persist on both create and update

    @JsonView(View.Create.class)
    private String strOnCreateOnly; //only persist on create, never on update
    //getters & setters
}
```

On your create method, marshall the class with the `Create` view. Then on the update method, simply use the `Common` or `Update` views.

Comment: Thanks!. I was under the impression JsonView is only for marshaling but I don't know enough. I'll give it a whirl and see if it works!

Comment: Looks like the views are not working when marshaling. Despite having the @JsonView on the controller like shown here http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-jsonview, it is still unmashaling the property

Comment: Hmmm... I will give it a try again later. But what we're doing to my previous project is similar to this. or maybe there's another way.